# How to get all parents/children categories of a custom taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I’m working on a custom WordPress theme and I want to show all the taxonomies list

So, for example, if I  want this structure:

1. Parent Category 1

   - Child Category 1
   - Child Category 2
   - Child Category 3

     > 1.1 - Grand Child Category 1
2. Parent Category 2

   - Child Category 4
   - Child Category 5

     > 2.1. - Grand Child Category 2

can you guys please help me to solve this puzzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create this structure, maybe going with a helper array is the solution. This is not a 100% solution it will just give you start up and you can go from here since figuring it out all alone will be more helpful.

```
$all_terms = array();
$taxonomy = 'category';
$parent_args = [
    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'    => false
];
$parent_terms = get_terms( $parent_args );

foreach ( $parent_terms as $parent_term ) {
   $all_terms[ $parent_term->term_id ] = get_all_term_children( $parent_term, $taxonomy );
}

function get_all_term_children( $term, $taxonomy ){
    if ( is_wp_error( get_term_children( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    return get_term_children( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function: replace "taxonomy_name" with your taxonomy.

```
wp_list_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name', 'title_li' => "") );
```

Output:

[image: Output look like this]

Note: I have used WP 4.9.8

Comment: @Rahulvats If this answer helps, then accept/upvote the answer.  :-)