# Custom Taxonomy List Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm really a beginner for creating and displaying custom tax on WordPress.

I created a custom Genre taxonomy and I'm displaying this with this:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'movie_genre' ); if( $terms ): ?>

                    
                    <!-- Movie Genre -->  
                    
                            <div class="slideout-heading">

                                    <div class="d-inline-block">
                                    <h5><?php esc_html_e( 'Genre'); ?></h5>
                                    </div>

                            </div>  
                    
                            <div class="row">
                            
                            <div class="carousel mb-3 w-100" data-flickity='{ "pageDots": false, "imagesLoaded": true, "prevNextButtons": true, "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true, "groupCells": true }'>
                            
                            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

                                <?php
                                    $attachment_id = get_field('taxonomy_image', $term);
                                    $size = "wp-img-square-profile"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                                    $genreimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
                                ?>      
                                    
                                <div class="col-3 py-3">
                                
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">                                    
                                    <?php if( $attachment_id ) { 
                                            echo '<img class="img-fluid border-class shadow-sm" src="'. $genreimage[0] .'" />';                              
                                        } else { 
                                            wp_default_img_placeholder(); 
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="author-list-name px-1">                         
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr ($term->name); ?></a>
                                    </div>                                  
                                    
                                </div>                  
                                
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            
                            </div>
                            
                            </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
                    </div>                          
                
                </div>
                
                </div>
```

How could I display Genres Parent & Child together another and other? I can display selected parent and child for the custom taxonomy but could not relate with a parent it's just showing one by one not related with the parent but I would like to relate the group Parent-Child :)

-Action

- best actor
- best music

-Adventure

- best music

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcWx2.png)

[Custom_Movie_Genre_Taxonomy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0B3M.png)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all parents/children categories of a custom taxonomy in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738580/how-to-get-all-parents-children-categories-of-a-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress)

Comment: nope, it's not worked at all :(

Comment: I just updated my question, I can display the parent and child but it's displaying all taxonomies so how could I display just only selected :)

Comment: What do you mean "display just only selected"? Your taxonomy is `Genre`, your terms are `Action, Comedy, Drama` - I think you are confusing those.

Comment: I have Parent Genre and Child Genre like Action(Parent)-Best Film(Child Genre-selected) - Best Actor(Child Genre- not selected) I can display selected parent and child but could not relate with a parent it's just showing one by one but I would like to related group Parent-Child :) So yeah maybe I just confused

Comment: Do not post code in comments. Edit your question and add that.

Comment: okay, thanks for the notice :)

Comment: I just tried a new solution which is working just to get the post taxonomies parent and child but again I could not relate the parent-child relationship. :( you can check my new output :)